# iOS: TapGestureRecognizer in UIView not fired

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have create an date component and have problems with the GestureRecognizer.

[image]

First line is a StackView with labels. If I attach a TapGestureRecognizer it is fired on touch. The following Lines are subviews in a Stackview consisting of a label and an image view. I can add the Recognizer to the subview, to the label or the image view. It never gets fired and I made sure that userInteraction is enabled.

What could be the problem?

Here an example how I add the recognizer:

```
func addTap(){
        dayLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:)))
    tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:)))
    tap3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:)))

    dayLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap1!)
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap2!)
    addGestureRecognizer(tap3!)
    }

    @objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        logger.debug("tap")
        changeSelection()
    }
```

You can find a little demo project boiled down to the problem here: https://github.com/ogezue/datedemo

Comment: Using a uicollectionview would be so much easier

Comment: is there any way you can create a small little project that recreates this?

Comment: good idea! I added the link above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Problem I can see is your view must be cover with Image and label 
and you are adding same   `UITapGestureRecognizer` to all so   that  is added on last object  say view (which is covered with image and label) so it may not able to get tap event

You need three different objects of  `UITapGestureRecognizer` you can't add same tap gesture on different views

Hope it may solve your problem

Comment: I changed it to 3 separate recognizers with no change. In first line it is working where I have just one label (but no subclass)

Answer (score 0):

For every view (*Label/Imageview*) you should create a *tap object* not the same one added to both . . .

Comment: did that now, but no change

Comment: Make isUserInteractionEnabled = true for every stackView

Comment: it is in storyboard